# how to get the value of textarea from innerhtml in javascript and insert into the database using the controller in laravel....?

Tags: laravel

**javascript**

```
 $(document).on('click', '#sidebar-user-box', function() {
    
     var userID = $(this).attr("class");
     var username = $(this).children().text() ;
     
     if ($.inArray(userID, arr) != -1)
     {
      arr.splice($.inArray(userID, arr), 1);
     }
     
     arr.unshift(userID);
     chatPopup =  '<div class="msg_box" style="right:270px" rel="'+ userID+'">'+
                    '<div class="msg_head">'+username +
                    '<div class="close">x</div> </div>'+
                    '<div class="msg_wrap"><div class="msg_body" id="msg_body" ><div class="msg_push"></div></div>'+
                    '<div class="msg_footer"><textarea class="msg_input" id="msg_input" rows="4" style="resize:none;"></textarea></div></div></div>' ;                   
                
     $("body").append(  chatPopup  );
     displayChatBox();
    });
    
    
    $(document).on('keypress', 'textarea' , function(e) {       
        if (e.keyCode == 13 ) {         
            var msg = $(this).val();        
            $(this).val('');
            if(msg.trim().length != 0){             
            var chatbox = $(this).parents().parents().parents().attr("rel") ;
            $('<div class="msg-right">'+msg+'</div>').insertBefore('[rel="'+chatbox+'"] .msg_push');
            $('.msg_body').scrollTop($('.msg_body')[0].scrollHeight);

    var url=  " /sendchatmessage ";
    $.ajax({
     headers:{'X-CSRF-token':$('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')},
      async:true,
        type:"post",
        contentType:false,
        url:url,
        data:msg,
        processData:false,
        success:function(){
          console.log("success");
        }
    });

}

 } // revision
  
 });
```

**controller**

```
    public function send_chat_message(Request $req){


            $name = $req->input('msg_input'); // 
            $newchat = new ChatMessage;
            $newchat->frsender_userId = Auth::user()->user_id;
            $newchat->frchat_msg = $name;
            $newchat->save();
        
        
    }
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/sendchatmessage', 'MessengerController@send_chat_message')->name('sent-chat');
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more the exact steps where the code is not working, I can't figure out what is actually the question, is it a JavaScript question?

Comment: i was creating popup chat box like facebook style using laravel. my problem is in the textarea i want to get the value of textarea from html inside javascript..because i dont know how to get the value in html from javascript and insert into the database.???

Comment: I think your question is too vague, you should share what type of debugging you have performed to let us help you.